# how to use class based views for a single page blog with pagination in django

Tags: python, django

[this is the error messag am getting in a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPpoJ.jpg)  someone should please help me solve this problem i have been on it for the past 3days,
i have a single blog which is handled by multiple author or admin,so i decided to use class based views and when i create a new post gives an error saying i need blog_detail.html,since i dont have detail blog so i created a Detailview then adding my template_name = 'mymainblogpage.html' so once i create new post it will get posted but wont show the post but will only show the pagination,besides i cant search by post id for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/blog/49/ i just get nothing here is my code.

## views.py

```
def blog(request):
    blog_post = Blog.objects.all()
    ordering = ['-timestamp']
    paginator = Paginator(blog_post, 2)
    page_request_var = 'page'
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(2)
    except EmptyPage:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages) 
    context = {
        'queryset': paginated_queryset,
        'page_request_var': page_request_var

    }

    return render(request, 'pages/blog.html', context)


class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'pages/blog.html'
    context_object_name = 'blog'
```

### urls.py

```
    path('blog/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
```

### models.py

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

### blog.html

```
     <br><p></p>
<section class="ftco-section bg-light" id="blog-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5 pb-5">
          <div class="col-md-10 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
            <h2 class="mb-4">Gets Every Single Updates Here</h2>
            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia</p>
          </div>
        </div>


      <div class="container">
         <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5 pb-5">
          <div class="col-lg-8 ftco-animate">
           {% for blog in queryset %}
            <h2 class="text-center">{{ blog.title }}</h2>
            <div class="meta mb-3 text-center">
           <div><h6><span><a href = "">written By {{ blog.user }}</span><small class="date"><i class="icon-clock"></i>  {{  blog.timestamp|timesince }} ago</small><a/></h6>

            </div>
            </div>
           <div><small class="icon-eye text-danger">{{ blog.view_count }}</small></div> 

          <div class="meta mb-3 text-center">

          <h5>{% for cat in blog.categories.all %}<span class="btn btn-dark">{{ cat }}</span> {% endfor %}</h5>

          </div>

           <p class="text-center">{{ blog.overview }}</p>
            {% endfor %}

            <nav aria-label="pagination">
                <ul class="pagination pagination-circle pg-blue">
                 {% if queryset.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item"><a href= "?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.previous_page_number }}"  class="page-link">Previous</a></li>
                 {% endif %}

                    <li class="page-item active"><a href= "?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.number }}" class="page-link">{{ queryset.number }}</a></li>
                   </a>
                  </li>
               {% if queryset.has_next %}
              <li class="page-item"><a  href= "?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.next_page_number }}" class="page-link">Next</a></li>
                {% endif %}
           </ul>
           </nav>
               {% if is_paginated %}
              <nav aria-label="pagination">
                <ul class="pagination pagination-circle pg-blue">
                 {% if queryset.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item"><a href= "?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.previous_page_number }}"  class="page-link">Previous</a></li>
                 {% endif %}

                    <li class="page-item active"><a href= "?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.number }}" class="page-link">{{ queryset.number }}</a></li>
                   </a>
                  </li>
               {% if queryset.has_next %}
              <li class="page-item"><a  href= "?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.next_page_number }}" class="page-link">Next</a></li>
                {% endif %}
           </ul>
           </nav>
           {% endif %}
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: what does your `pages/blog.html` file look like?

Comment: its my blog page,i already built it, but just single showing the title,the author,the category,and the overview of the a post then pagination under

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pagination isn't showing because you are passing context variable `'page_request_var': page_request_var` instead of `'page_request_var': page`
so change it because `page_request_var` is just a string `'page'`. 
If you need to use class-based list view then

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class PostListView(ListView):
  queryset = Post.published.all()
  context_object_name = 'posts' # by default class list view uses object_list.
  paginate_by = 2   # number of objects/posts per page 
  template_name = 'pages/blog.html' # by default uses <appname>/<modelname>_<view_type>.html
```

also, I would recommend using different templates for list and detail views because you are just searching the same template using  so I think that may be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much I used class based view instead